# Magento 2: Customize 2nd checkout step

Tags: magento2, checkout, payment

If customer change billing address, i want add this like shipping infomation. How to do this? please help me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please override this file to your theme like :

vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/shipping-information.html

to

app/design/frontend/theme/default/Magento_Checkout/web/shipping-information.html